# Was the NGO Safeguard Defenders founded in 2016 or in 2019?

Tags: spain

The Spanish NGO Safeguard Defenders claims on their [website](https://safeguarddefenders.com/en/about-us) in different languages to have been founded in 2016.

> Safeguard Defenders is a human rights NGO founded in late 2016 [...]

> The foundation for Safeguard Defenders was laid in 2016, and was publicly launched in 2017.

According to the [official registration papers](https://www.boe.es/diario_boe/txt.php?id=BOE-A-2020-8052) it was only founded in June 2019.

> La Fundación anteriormente citada fue constituida por don Peter Jesper Dahlin [...] el 13 de junio de 2019 con el número 767 de protocolo.

Is the organization lying about their foundation date, or is there some other explanation?  For example, was there a precursory organization of the same name existing unofficially outside Spain?

PS:  I do not doubt that China is prosecuting its citizens abroad, and it is not the aim of my questions to defend the Chinese government.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This question appears to be based on a simple misunderstanding of definitions.

The founding of an organisation, and the establishment of a foundation under Spanish Law are two different things.

Collins English Dictionary defines [founding](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/founding) as "relating to the starting of a particular institution or organization."

The founding of the organisation was in 2016, and by 2017 they had created their website. The Internet Archive started crawling it in [November 2017](https://web.archive.org/web/20171126070315/https://safeguarddefenders.com/). That version includes a blog entry dated August 1, 2017 announcing the launch of Safeguard Defenders.

The registration of the organisation as a foundation in Spain's [Registro de Fundaciones](https://www.mjusticia.gob.es/ca/ciudadania/registros/fundaciones-competencia/informacion-general/registro-fundaciones) (Registry of Foundations) came in mid-2019, according to the link you provided.